# Sharepoint Designer 2010 Deployment of CSS, masterpage and general brand

Tags: moss

What is the stand best method for deploying the style, masterpage, branding I have created on my site to a live environment. I've looked at creating a solution file but this doesn't seem to carry styling.

Can someone pleae point me in the correct direction?

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to create Solution Package (wsp file) and apply your branding in `FeatureActivated` method.